Error when downloading ZIP archive containing multiple files
I'm having trouble downloading a zip archive containing multiple files. When I try to open the downloaded archive, I encounter an error. Here's how I'm generating the paths to the files:
public/files/news/downloadable/3C1FVuFx13iH4og3zjferjx8qhQj1js2RUqDOCXG.pdf
public function downloadAllCertificates(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $certificateIds = $request->input('certificate_ids');

        $zipFileName = 'all_certificates.zip';
        $zipFilePath = public_path($zipFileName);
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open(public_path($zipFileName), \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        foreach ($certificateIds as $certificateId) {
            $certificate = UserCertificate::findOrFail($certificateId);
            $filePath = storage_path('app/' . $certificate->path);
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $zip->addFile($filePath);
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("File not found for certificate ID: $certificateId");
            }
        }

        $zip->close();

        $zipSize = filesize($zipFilePath);

        return response()->download(public_path($zipFileName));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create zip file'], 500);
    }
}

I've tried downloading the files individually, and that works fine. However, I get an error when I put them into a zip archive and try to download it. I suspect there's an issue with how I'm creating the archive.
Additionally, I checked the size of my archive using the filesize() function, and it returned 265,530 bytes. Is this a standard size for an archive containing two PDF files?
Any help or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

"I get an error" ... such as ... ?

"Is this a standard size for an archive containing two PDF files?" - There's no way to answer this, as it's unknown what the PDF files contain. Are they catalogues with hundreds of pages, or a short, text-intensive, user manual, with selectable text, and little to no graphics? What happens when you download two files separately, and then create a zip archive out of them? Is that archive close in size to what you get with a (presumably) faulty one?

Also, since you've hard-coded a static zip file name into your application, if there are two download requests at the same time at least one will corrupt or overwrite the other, if not both being corrupted.

@AlexHowansky I am sorry, I get error "An error occurred while loading the archive

@FiddlingAway I am just for testing downloading two simple pdf files (just one page) and it downloaded as crashed zip archive. I tried to download pdf files itself and it works, but when I try to put them in archive it does not

@Sammitch yeah, that probably can when it will be released in product, but now I am only user of this functionality and it does not work :(

Do you have proper PHP error reporting and logging enabled, and checked what the error log might have to say about this?

I found a solution. I needed to add these:ob_start(), ob_end_clean() to my code and it worked.
